# R function Failure in UDx RPC call InvokeGetUdxType() Issue

Tags: r, vertica

I am tring to create an **R** function in **Vertica** and i am getting an error. 
Any help or clue would be highly apreaciated

```
dbadmin=> create transform function pred as language 'R' name 'pred' library predLb;
ROLLBACK 3399:  Failure in UDx RPC call InvokeGetUdxType(): Error calling getUdxType() in User Defined Object [predict] at [/scratch_a/release/16125/vbuild/vertica/OSS/UDxFence/vertica-udx-R.cpp:209], error code: 0, message: Error happened in getUdxType : Exception in processing required attribute udxtype in the factory function : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

**#dbLog error**

```
Starting UDxSideProcess for language R
with command line: /opt/vertica/bin/vertica-udx-R 3 node-32420:0x61c5 debug-log-off /home/dbadmin/stream/v_stream_node0001_catalog/UDxLogs
```

**#Error from the UDx log**

```
/home/dbadmin/stream/v_stream_node0001_catalog/UDxLogs/UDxFencedProcesses.log 
2015-06-24 11:15:55.922 [R-node-32420:0x61c5-2308] 0x7f3c460457a0 UDx side process started
11:15:55.922 [R-node-32420:0x61c5-2308] 0x7f3c460457a0 My port: 46526
11:15:55.922 [R-node-32420:0x61c5-2308] 0x7f3c460457a0 My address: 0.0.0.0
11:15:55.922 [R-node-32420:0x61c5-2308] 0x7f3c460457a0 Vertica port: 37765
11:15:55.922 [R-node-32420:0x61c5-2308] 0x7f3c460457a0 Vertica address: 127.0.0.1
11:15:55.922 [R-node-32420:0x61c5-2308] 0x7f3c460457a0 Vertica address family: 2
11:15:55.946 [R-node-32420:0x61c5-2309] 0x7f3c460457a0 UDx_ereport: Exception in processing required attribute udxtype in the factory function : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "NULL"
11:15:55.946 [R-node-32420:0x61c5-2309] 0x7f3c460457a0 UDx_ereport: Error happened in getUdxType : Exception in processing required attribute udxtype in the factory function : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "NULL"
11:15:55.946 [R-node-32420:0x61c5-2309] 0x7f3c460457a0 Error in recv(): Vertica process has exited abnormally
11:15:58.003 [R-node-32420:0x61c5-2308] 0x7f3c460457a0 Received SIGTERM, exiting
```

Comment: Have you tried Vertica community yet?

Comment: This was run on top of a community version ! Could this be the problem ?

Comment: I just don't think many HP folks are following StackOverflow.

Comment: Actually i've posted the same on R forum on HP, and they helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer ! 
Actually there is nothing wrong with the R libs it was just a spelling matter ! :(, not on my part. I don't review R Udx code. 
The R function name is pred is different.